# How to catch command line print output of git bash when calling from python?

Tags: python, bash, git, subprocess, merge-file

Suppose I have 3 text files ours.txt, base.txt and theirs.txt and want to do a three way merge on them. When I call `git merge-file -p ours.txt base.txt theirs.txt` in Git Bash, it will print the merged text.

Whereas, when I run

```
import subprocess

dir = "path/to/text files"
cmd = ["git", "merge-file", "-p ", "ours.txt", "base.txt", "theirs.txt"]
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, cwd=dir)
```

I can access `stdout` and  `stderr` through

```
(out, error) = p.communicate()
```

But can't seem to store the merged text that gets printed in Git Bash in a variable.

Does anybody have any ideas on how to retrieve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can get the text read into a file with var=$(git merge-file -p ours.txt base.txt theirs.txt)

Comment: That would be a variable in git BASH, right?

Comment: your code works on my machine (python 3.8.5, linux). What python/OS are you running ?

Comment: Python 3.8.5, Windows 10.

Comment: what happens if you *don't* capture stdout ? does the expected output get printed on the console you run your python program from ?